# SharePoint Online REST: Get User Profile Properties in 2013 Workflow

Tags: 2013, rest, designer-workflow, web-services, user-profile-property

I'm looking for some help with a REST call I'm attempting to make in SharePoint Designer 2013 Workflow. The site is on SharePoint Online.

The call is to get info related to a specific user account.

The call I am using is this: `<site url>/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor(accountName=@v)?@v='i%3A0%23.f|membership|example@example.com'`

If I manually append this call to the site I am building the workflow for in the browser, I get the required info back. However if I do the exact same call in a workflow "Call HTTP Web Service" action, in an app step, I get an "Unauthorized" response from the call.

I have granted permissions to the workflow app using the app ID with a permissions request of:

```
<AppPermissionRequests><AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/sitecollection/web" Right="FullControl" />
</AppPermissionRequests>
```

I have attempted to add an empty "Authorized" header in the call as some posts have suggested this and that caused a "Forbidden" response.

Any help or feedback on this would be great. Please let me know if more info is required.

Thanks

Comment: You write that you used Authorized. I use an empty Authorization string in the headers. Don't know if that's the cause

Comment: Yes sorry thats what I meant, will update my question. I am using an empty Authorization string :)

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the Authorization empty in the RequestHeaders , 
set Content-Type and Accept

to

```
Accept : application/json;odata=verbose
Content-Type : application/json;odata=verbose
```

[Check this for more info](https://sergeluca.wordpress.com/2013/04/09/calling-the-sharepoint-2013-rest-api-from-a-sharepoint-designer-workflow/)

Check in the web service properties that the RequestHeaders points correctly to your dictionary that contains (Authorization,Content-Type and Accept). It happened to me that I absend-mindedly put it in ResponseHeaders

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This causes the exact same Unauthorized error in the response code returned by the call unfortunately.

Comment: Maybe you could try with a rest service that don'require accountName like the one in the url I wrote. Just to restrict the problem.